# Specify valid values for a Core Data attribute

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data

When I'm using Core Data I'm sometimes in a situation where I have an
attribute than can only have a specific set of possible values. As an
example let's say that you make a bug tracker and you have an entity
called Bug. Then it's possible that you want an attribute for the
state that the bug is in. Let's say that possible states are Open,
Closed and In Progress.

What I've done so far is that I've had attributes like that defined as
strings. Usually I've had a combo box or a radio group in the user
interface and the possible input values have been defined by what the
possible selections the combo box or radio group offers.

One of the problems with this approach is that it doesn't work if the
application is localized it into a different language. Then the word
which indicates the state is stored differently depending on the
current language. I need to save the selection in a language
independent manner.

How would you do that?

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this:

In the Data Model Editor, define an `Integer 16` property for your `Bug` entity to keep the three states. In your `Bug` class this will be an `NSNumber` object.

The actual displayed string of this number should be handled by your program. To keep this logic neatly encapsulated, add the appropriate methods to your `Bug.m`. For example like this:

```
-(NSString *)stateTitle {
    NSString *title = NSLocalizedString(@"None", nil);
    if ([self.state intValue]==1) return NSLocalizedString(@"Open", nil);
    if ([self.state intValue]==2) return NSLocalizedString(@"Closed", nil);
    if ([self.state intValue]==3) return NSLocalizedString(@"In Progress", nil);
    return title;
}
```

Now, in your UI classes you can simply use `[theBug stateTitle]` to display the proper localized description e.g. in a `UILabel`.